# Auto-size for PNG icons defined in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm defining PNG icons for use in buttons in CSS. How can I define `.icon-test` without hardcoding both `height` and `width`?

I'd like to define only *one of them*, and let the other one be inferred automatically, without having to manually care about the aspect ratio.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-test {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/32x15);
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 8em;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<a class="button"><i class="icon icon-test"></i> BUTTON</a>
```

Note: What's the standard way to do this, in order to import a pack of icons, easily available with CSS classes e.g. `<span class="icon icon-ok"></span>`?

Comment: use <img> instead of background-image

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd like to define dozens of such icons in a CSS file, for later use with just `<span class="icon icon-ok"></span>`, or `<i ...></i>`. Woulnd't you use CSS for this?

Comment: if you need the element to have a given size set by a css rule, you could have such rule given with a class selector like `.icon` that will set the size and another class for the specific image. Then you'll always use the `icon` class on all your pictures and each one will have also the specific class for the picture.

Comment: @diegod Not sure to see exactly... Would you have an example (maybe in a code snippet / answer)?

Comment: You haven't explained how you expect an element with no content to arrive at a size. There's no relation between a background and the element's size.

Comment: @isherwood I'd like to define the width manually (e.g. `2em`), the background-image file, and then the content size should be automatically adapted to the image, keeping aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that's like expecting paint to hold up a wall.

Comment: That is simply not possible with a background image. You will have to have both width and height in your CSS. If you want always the same width, then you can put that in your `.icon` class - and the _specific_ width for the `test`-icon would then go into the `.icon-test` class. If you want the height value to use to be determined automatically - then implement a gulp task or something, that reads all the image files from a folder, and _dynamically_ creates the necessary CSS.

Comment: @Basj just move the `width` and `height` attributes value to the rule defined by the `.icon` selector and all the elements having that class will be styled as that using that size. It will be defined once for all. And every single rule specific for each single image will be defined with its own class.

Comment: @isherwood What's the standard way to do this, in order to import a pack of icons, easily available with CSS classes?

Comment: There isn't one. That's not a standard approach. Normally folks want all their icons to be the same size.

Comment: worth mentioning [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Resizing_background_images) and [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice is to use background sizing on the element as you have it. You can use `contain` to be sure that your icon images aren't cropped, and set them to not repeat.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-test {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/32x15);
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: pink; /* for demo only */
}

.two {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/15x32);
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 8em;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<a class="button"><i class="icon icon-test"></i> BUTTON</a>

<a class="button"><i class="icon icon-test two"></i> BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: isn't redundant to specificy the background-image as something that will override the rule given by the .icon-test selector when also the class two is applied? isn't it better as I was trying to say since the beginning to specify the size once and for all in .icon? and maybe use background-size instead?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The particular image can be applied any number of ways. I just did this to demonstrate two different aspect ratios.

Comment: I just see that the second "button" has an icon set through two classes (`icon-test two`) which css rules collide on the background-image and that the second one overrides the first not for reason bound to strict specificity. Anyway never mind. I probably was confused since the beginning and didn't get the question at all. I still don't like this solution but probably it's my own problem

Comment: and by the way the picture is cropped instead of resized like it would be if using background-size. So I still really don't get why the sizes were not defined just in the .icon rule instead of hardcoding them in one the specific classes holding the picture

Comment: Your first sentence is faulty. I _am_ using background-size, and `cover` crops while `contain` doesn't. The size _could_ be defined on `.icon`. It's not my code, so I left it alone.